# Overwriting iframe form field AND requesting information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an assignment for one of my classes where I need to bypass CSRF protection and login with a specific account even if the user inputs different credentials. Right now I did it in a kind of hack-y way that works when there is no CSRF protection (place an invisible submit button for my form on top of the iframe's submit button). Anyway, so how would I overwrite the username and password fields (using Jquery I presume) of the iframe when the login button (in the iframe) is pressed?

mytest.com:

```
<html>
<head><title>mytest.com</title></head>
<body>
     <iframe id="testFrame" src="test.com" allowfullscreen width="110%" height="900px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

test.com:

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline" id="form0">
    <input id="user" name="user" type="text" placeholder="username" required>
    <input id="pass" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="password" required>
    <button id="submitBut" type="submit" formaction="test.com">login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: It's just a standard form with two input fields and a submit button inside an iframe where the iframe is the only thing on the page. So there's my page (mytest.com) and the iframe src (test.com). On test.com there is an login form that no matter what the user inputs, when the user presses login, the forms username/password field should be re-written (OR the login button should submit a hidden form on mytest.com.

Comment: So, you want the volunteers on SO to do your homework for you, but you don't even want to provide them with a starting point?

Comment: No, I want someone to point me in the right direction as to how I should approach the problem. I shouldn't need to include the code for the form or the main page seeing as it's about as basic as a form can get and the main page just has an iframe in it. But since it will make you feel better, I've added the very complicated code to my post.